# How to change the parent user on my chat profile

Tags: discussion, chat, profile-page

I cannot change the parent user shown in my chat profile. I've deleted my GL&U account a few months ago, then people get the 404 error when trying to see my profile. When I click on change, this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: A moderator suggested to do it for me, but it didn't work for him as well.

Comment: I'll fix it; probably the same situation as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126840/chat-user-has-no-parent-user/126936#126936

Comment: Fixed, I've set your parent user to your math account, you should be able to change it again.