# Accessing a user profile from chat led to 404 error - Page not found

Tags: bug, chat, profile-page, 404-not-found

I saw [this](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9026122#9026122) message in Tavern chat by a given user and I wanted to visit their profile, but heading to their profile page led me to a 404 error.

[image: 404]

I tried to search about this (I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126840/chat-user-has-no-parent-user)) and ask on Tavern chat but it led nowhere.

Please fix this error which confuses users who try to visit user profiles from chat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chat user has no parent user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126840/chat-user-has-no-parent-user)

Comment: The newest related Q&As: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305211/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305211/282094 and old: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129385/282094 - and "Related" links in right column.

Comment: No, I already mention that on question.

Comment: They all are old question and doesn't address the question.

Comment: @Shree It should be fixable now (and has been for a while), but we often encounter the obstacle of many little things needing a fix and not enough time. I'm glad you posted it again anyhow, it might happen this time.

Comment: After searching for their user name, I found that user's profile here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/960635/snow. It's weird that they don't have the same ID though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one delete a chat profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283432/282094)

Comment: **NO**  That's not neither its duplicate ?

Comment: As the duplicate explains: Once the user has a large chat history deleting their account breaks the link to their profile, and that **CORRECTLY** is a 404. The server can **NOT** detect a bug and apply a fix OFT, if it could there would be no bug reports, or spam. -- The 404 is not the error, as explained in the duplicate they are fixing these incomplete merges manually after the user asks. --- If your request is: script a search for all broken links, write each a redirect to a page explaining the problem, and fix the code so this doesn't continue, ***then*** **that** is what you should ask.