# Make account merges propagate to chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, merge-accounts

When two accounts are merged, all the posts/votes are moved over to the "primary" account, and the other account ("sock"?) is deleted. The merge is propagated network-wide, so a similar thing happens on each site.

But, this does not happen to the chat user. The "sock" chat user is kept, with a 404 parent profile link. I feel that the chat user should be merged as well, re attributing all the chat messages.

Thoughts?

Comment: This is also the case when accounts are deleted, not just merged. (Or at least self-deleted; I don't have experience with moderator deletion.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Not sure, I [think part of it is fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126840/chat-user-has-no-parent-user). Though there still may be an issue with deleting the account on the parent site, making the user into a broken window. A note: aside from the conditions in which it can be done, mod-deletion is the same thing as user self-deletion. Though we have a destroy option as well.

Comment: [Here's a chat account that is still associated with a user account I self-deleted several months ago](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/47466/island). However, the Stack Exchange account still existed (it had accounts on other sites).

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Oh. That's sort of [status-bydesign]--deleting one account doesn't mean that all should be deleted. If one deletes their account on a given site, the deletion isn't propagated. But yeah, if the user has no main accounts left after the deletion, then the chat account should be deleted.

Comment: Deleting a chat account also deletes all of the chat messages by that user. That's not something we necessarily want to happen in every case. However, we can anonymize chat messages now, so we could *possibly* tie into that. I vaguely recall a feature request somewhere that talked about doing it automatically for deleted user accounts, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: @Adam three and half years later, think it's possible? Though rare, it's causing bugs like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279466/chat-not-working-after-account-merge)