# Chat not working after account merge

Tags: bug, chat, merge-accounts

I have recently merged accounts.

However, it looks like the chats weren't been influenced by the merge, which makes me underprivileged to participate in chat. The screenshots of the problem are as follows:

> [image]

The chats homepage still shows the new account which I used after my past account was locked:

> [image]

So, **it looks like there was a minor glitch with the merge, where chat didn't get influenced.**

---

[Update]:  It has been two weeks and the problem persists. Looks like it isn't a caching problem.

In fact, this has been [recognised and confirmed in the SFF chat too](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29913738#29913738). (by @Randal'thor)

Comment: Caching? Changing your user name or avatar on one of the main sites takes some time to propagate to chat. Perhaps the same applies after a merge?

Comment: @DavidPostill It's been a day already :)

Comment: And if you click that `[change]` link? because I don't have that in my chat profile?

Comment: @David no caching,  it's a known issue and there's already a feature request asking to support such thing: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159938/make-account-merges-propagate-to-chat.

Comment: @rene Tried it. It doesn't work, as that chat acc. is still tied to the new one I created after my old acc was locked.  So, it shows only the Startups SE in the drop-down!

Comment: Well, it was worth a try ... let's wait for a dev ...

Comment: @rene almost 6 years later, no dev ever popped anywhere near this bug report. And never will, of course.

Comment: @sha well, chat has been and probably remains the ugly stepchild of SE. If only they had listened to Jon ...

Comment: @rene well merge breaks so many other things as well, even the staff indicator. And they still won't waste even fraction of a nanosecond to fix any of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have mailed the SO team about the problem, and they have deleted the chat account of the new account.

And thus, my sweet chat is back. Here is their response on mail:

> [image]