# Changing email address associated with account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Is it possible to change the email address associated with all my stack exchange accounts, and can I do this from the Android app?

The Android app logs me in automatically but not my web browser at the moment and I even forgot the actual email address associated with my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [How do I change the email address associated with my Stack Exchange OpenID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102392/302377)

If that doesn't work/is not your problem, the please follow the below procedure.

You can create an account with your new email address, and then you [need to mail the SO team about the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) (so that they can merge the accounts), and they would ask a couple of questions for confirming authenticity, and they would then merge the accounts manually.

I had a [similar problem a week back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279466/302377), and the linked post shows the proceedings.