# Reputation is not updated when merging chat accounts

Tags: bug, reputation, chat, merge-accounts

I had 2 accounts, e.g:

```
Account 1 having : 1000 reputation.
Account 2 having : 50 reputation.
```

After merging these two: the reputation while on the Stack Overflow **site** shows the updated Reputation i.e. 1050, whereas in **chat** it shows reputation as: 1000.

Comment: Not really a bug. Chat never supported merging of the parent account, usually it [just cause the chat profile to break](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279466/chat-not-working-after-account-merge) until a developer manually fix it, so consider yourself lucky. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard : No but, as a user perspective it of course is a bug. Wherein we are just are comparing the Better version of the Bug which is occurring. Ideally this doesn't match the Expected behavior. Though this might be a low priority, but important thing is If not known, then it should be on the List, as we being the Patrons of SO. :)