# 500 internal server error when trying to access chat profile

Tags: support, bug, chat, 500-server-error

I tried going on the Stack Overflow chat and got the following notice:

[image]

The console shows:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

### Update #1

It seems like this issue intermittently occurs.

### Update #2

**Browser:** Chrome (60.0.3112.113)

**Access Type:** HTTPS

**VPN:** N/A

**Country:** UK

Comment: Specific browser? Are you using TOR, a VPN service? In which part of the world are you? If you switch ISP's does the same issue occur? You did load over https, right? Are you hitting a specific url?

Comment: @rene How am I supposed to switch ISP?

Comment: Maybe use your mobile phone as a WiFi AP and use your mobile data provider

Comment: Most likely your account was merged at some point, this screws up the chat profile, always did. SE employee (developer or a Community Manager) must manually re-create your chat account.

Comment: Yup, found it. [This is your other account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3554833/), most likely your chat profile is still there, deleted, and not merged into your new account. Next time you can save time by saying that's the case.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I can't figure out how a 500-error chat access heisenbug can *possibly* be a dupe of a 100% repeatable 404-error chat *profile* access error.

Comment: @Nathan sorry thought the other one was 500 error and not 100% reproduceable. Anyway [this is a better dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279466/chat-not-working-after-account-merge) and confirms what I said in the comment. Since it is case by case, better just leave all those reports open anyway.

Comment: Yeah... @ShaWiz got the cause here. I've deleted the orphaned chat account  so if you try and join chat now it should recreate you a new chat account that works.

Comment: @Jon oh, thought only SE employee can handle those cases as it involves merging... cheers!

Comment: @ShaWiz in the case where it's an unused 5 year old chat (or a very infrequently used one) it's easier for a mod to just nuke the chat account to let the system create a new one. For frequent chatters with a large amount of chat history then yeah - best to get an employee involved so chat history is associated and retained correctly.