# My chat profiles were not merged when my accounts were merged

Tags: support, chat, merge-accounts, multiple-accounts

I recently merged my multiple accounts. All my reputations, badges, chat ping notifications, privilege notifications, etc. from my duplicate account were moved to my primary (original) account. But my chat profile of duplicate account is still existing as separate even after the account merge.

Before merging, I used my duplicate account for chatting with a different user name and made it to the list of RO by removing my primary one. I have noticed that even though after merging I am getting all the *reply to message* ping notifications to the chat messages from  my duplicate account in my primary account and at the same time couldn't able to access to the privilege of RO back.

So do account merges not merge/delete the chat profiles, or will it take time for a merge/automated deletion to happen?

If it's the case that the other chat account will never be merged/deleted after an account merge: Why does the current system keep the duplicate chat account as it was?

Comment: Your first question is addressed in [How does one delete a chat profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283431/how-does-one-delete-a-chat-profile): *Note that* merging *doesn't do [any automatic thing]. Thus, merging accounts where the account being merged from has an associated chat profile will very likely leave things in a bit of a weird state.* Also, *So for merge cases [...] you'll have to contact us if you want something done.*

Comment: There's a [pending feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159938/377214) asking for automatic merges of chat profiles on site account mergers. I think it was skipped at the time because at the time, specific site accounts could be merged without merging the whole network account, which would create problems with chat profile association: this is no longer possible today.