# Finding a SE user from a chat user whose parent user is on a dead site

Tags: support, chat, users, closed-sites

At https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3786, the "parent user" link links to a user page on a dead site, and that URL redirects to the Area 51 proposal page for that site. Is there a way to see this chat user's user page on another site or Stack Exchange instead?

Comment: Similar (non-dupe): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126840

Answer (score 2):

I think this is currently not possible. Regular moderators cannot assign a different parent site for these users, because the UI for that [is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126840/chat-user-has-no-parent-user).

What should happen when a chat user has a closed beta as parent site: Assign **Area51** as new parent site automatically. I couldn’t find this user on Area51, he might use another name there.