# User exists but clicking on the name shows 404 page

Tags: bug, chat, profile-page, users, 404-not-found

The following user was in the PHP room (had also visited before many times). When I clicked on the *user profile on stackoverflow.com* link, it redirected me to a 404 page. But the user exists if searched from the users tab on Stack Overflow:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/686733/jamshid-hashimi - 404
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/461181/jamshid-hashimi - Real Profile

Is this a result of profile merging? If yes, than why there are 2 different links for the same user?

[To test the issue](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/686733/jamshid-hashimi)

Comment: reproduced [follow here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/686733/jamshid-hashimi)

Comment: @CRUSADER added to the question, thanks

Comment: The chat user wasn't merged for some reason.

Comment: Related bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126840/152859