# Parent profile on chat is not updated if the account is deleted

Tags: bug, chat, user-accounts, parent-user

In [Stack Exchange chat server](https://chat.stackexchange.com/), every user has a parent profile and it is linked to a site. They are shown as affiliated to that site. e.g [My profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/202339/nog-shine) is linked to Movies & TV.

Now, I have seen some user profiles who have a site linked as parent site but their account is deleted. [A user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/275951/anurag-singh) was active on chat after their account on the site is deleted.

Why are the chat profiles not updated? How are users able to chat even when they have no account on parent sites?

Comment: Related: [Chat user has no parent user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126840)

Comment: @SFTP That is the same problem here too. The problem rose again.

Comment: We'll now delete chat profiles if ALL associated main-site profiles are gone, but the problem of deleting the one main-site profile associated with the chat profile remains.

Comment: @Shog9 Only the user profile on the site associated with chat profile was deleted. They have profiles on other SE sites. Is complete deletion of chat profile needed? Automatic change to other site is enough.

Comment: Yes, it would be enough. If we did it.