# How can this chat user chat without a parent user?

Tags: support, chat, chatbot, chat-profile, parent-user

Related: [Chat user has no parent user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126840/336163).

In the question above, a chat user's profile showed a link to a parent user, but that parent user turned out to be deleted when attempting to visit it on the parent site. Lately, I've seen the Stack Exchange chat user [Processed Meat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-589/) post chat messages *without having a parent user link at all*. That is, instead of their parent user link being a dead link, they appear to have no parent user at all.

How is this user chatting without any semblance of a parent user to give them the initial minimum reputation required to chat? Is this a grandfathered user from a time before chat users had to link in a main site parent user? Was this user's parent user not only a deleted user, but a deleted user on a *site* that was completely deleted?

This doesn't seem to be a relic of the past - a review of the chat user's [recent tab](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-589/?tab=recent) shows that they have chatted as recently as today.

Yes, a review of this user's recent posts indicates strong bot-like behavior, but bots in chat are held to the same basic technical and privilege standards as the rest of us.

Comment: It is a user with a negative userid. That are not real accounts but just monikers for feeds. Mods can create them at will, IIRC. Started [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=31989690#31989690). Same is true for other feed users: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/11540/charcoal-hq?tab=feeds

Comment: @rene - Yep. Mods have a "create user" button on different feeds in the room settings, which will create a feeds user. Mods can then edit the username and avatar of the feed.

Comment: @Mithical thanks, I wasn't sure if a mod had to pick an existing one and then fiddle with it. Good to know they can create them.