# Instance of chat user without parent user

Tags: bug, chat, user-accounts, parent-user

[This](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/472278/snapdragon-x) [Chat user has no parent user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126840/317948).

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard As a previous observation on Meta SE. I flagged such an account and it was rejected, so I think it's not much of a concern.

Comment: @QueenieGoldstein I was wrong, forgot about comment from staff explaining the situation. TL;DR: if a user posted more than 1000 messages in chat, their chat profile won't get deleted, and **even moderators and CM's can't delete it.** (Only developer with direct access to DB.)