# Error in reputation points from Stack Exchange and main site account deleted

Tags: support, chat, user-accounts, parent-user

A few months ago I deleted my main [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) (SO.es) account with around 4.5K reputation.

I have created an account again and when I see my reputation in SO.es I have 250 points.

[image]

And in I [SO.es.../repu...](https://es.stackoverflow.com/reputation) see:

```
total votes: 56
 3    383755 (0)
 2    383755 (10)
-- 2020-08-21 rep +10   = 11
 2    383755 (10)
 2    383755 (10)
 2    383755 (10)
 3    383755 (-2)
-- 2020-08-24 rep +28   = 39
 2    383755 (10)
-- 2020-08-26 rep +10   = 49
 2    383755 (10)
-- 2020-08-29 rep +10   = 59
 2    383755 (10)
-- 2021-01-04 rep +10   = 69
 2    383755 (10)
-- 2021-01-22 rep +10   = 79
 2    383755 (10)
-- 2021-01-25 rep +10   = 89
-- 2021-06-12 rep 0     = 89
 2    383755 (10)
-- 2021-11-16 rep +10   = 99
 3    383755 (-2)
-- 2022-04-05 rep -2    = 97
-- bonuses   (100)
-- 2022-12-15 rep +100  = 197
 3    576068 (-1)
 3    576070 (-1)
 2    576020 (10)
 2    576020 (10)
 16   576106 (2)
 16   576066 (2)
-- 2022-12-29 rep +22   = 219
-- 2023-01-03 rep 0     = 219
 3    576793 (-1)
 1    576916 (15)
 2    576916 (10)
 3    576923 (-1)
-- 2023-01-04 rep +23   = 242
 3    576020 (-2)
 2    576231 (10)
-- 2023-01-05 rep +8    = 250
-- 2023-01-07 rep 0     = 250

** rep today: 0
** rep this week (2023-01-08 - 2023-01-14): 0
** rep this month (2023-01-01 - 2023-01-31): 31
** rep this quarter (2023-01-01 - 2023-03-31): 31
** rep this year (2023-01-01 - 2023-12-31): 31
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 250 :)

days represented 16
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 0 days
earned 4 reputation from suggested edits
```

This all looks good and is correct, but when I go to my profile on the Stack Exchange network I see this:

[image]

I don't know if this is a bug; but it seems even after months of deleting the main account with data linked to the network account:

1. is this normal behavior?
2. If there is still data linked, would it be possible to recover those reputation points that are reflected?

Comment: This is because your chat profile is still associated to your now-deleted old profile on SOes: [Chat user has no parent user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126840/chat-user-has-no-parent-user). A moderator or SE employee can re-associate your chat profile correctly.

Comment: ok what I need to do that???

Comment: Ping an SOes moderator in one of their chat rooms. If they don't respond, use the [contact form](//es.stackoverflow.com/contact).